# Join two tables by historical date

Tags: sql, presto, trino

my difficulty is to join two tables with gmv value.

table 1

```
| id       | historical_date|     status     |
| -------- | -------------- | -------------- |
| 45615266 | 2021-06-02     | Pending        |
| 45615266 | 2021-12-05     | Validated      |
```

table 2

```
| id       | grass_date     |     value      |
| -------- | -------------- | -------------- |
| 45615266 | 2021-02-02     | 24.02          |
| 45615266 | 2021-03-17     | 15.48          |
| 45615266 | 2020-12-21     | 1993.85        |
| 45615266 | 2021-06-02     | 74.56          |
| 45615266 | 2021-07-14     | 74.48          |
| 45615266 | 2021-12-04     | 99.48          |
```

Expected

```
| id       | historical_date |     status     | grass_date     | value          |
| 45615266 | 2021-06-02      | Pending        | 2021-02-02     | 24.02          |
| 45615266 | 2021-06-02      | Pending        | 2021-03-17     | 15.48          |
| 45615266 | 2021-06-02      | Pending        | 2020-12-21     | 1993.85        |
| 45615266 | 2021-12-05      | Validated      | 2021-06-02     | 74.56          |
| 45615266 | 2021-12-05      | Validated      | 2021-07-14     | 74.48          |
| 45615266 | 2021-12-05      | Validated      | 2021-12-04     | 99.48          |
```

I use Trino (prestoSQL) and the subquery is limited to one column

Comment: What does "gmv value" mean?

Comment: just the description of "value" column

Comment: You need to explain the relationship between the tables that's used to produce the result. It looks like some relationship between `grass_date` and `historical_date`, but it's not obvious because they're not equal.

Comment: The historical_date means when the id change his status and the Grass_date, means when the id get the values in table 2... the relashioship is when the id make certain value, it changes status

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `NATURAL JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table 1 NATURAL JOIN table 2
```

Comment: This will join on the `id` column, producing a full cross product since all the IDs are the same.

Comment: I believe he wants to join `grass_date` with the next `historical_date` that's after it.

Comment: Hello, here says "natural join not supported"

Comment: @Barmar, exactly... the expected table, I can bring what values and dates were processed and when it changed status

Comment: ok may be with FULL JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id ?

Comment: i tried before, they duplicate the value "pending" in "validated"